# Equation System: Addition (Beamer / Article)

Tags: beamer, amsmath, cases

I'm trying to recreate something like the image below, found in a book. It is part of the solution to an equation system.

[image]

I have been able to create the equation system using the `cases` environment, provided by the `amsmath` package. I still need to add the "+" sign and also the line below the system.

I'm using `beamer`, but I'll need to use the same idea for an `article` later on. How can that be achieved?

Thank you!

Edit: Here's a `MWE`, using the `article` class:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$ 
\begin{cases} x + y = 1 \\ x  - y = -1 \end{cases} 
$

\end{document}
```

Comment: How about you show us the code you already have and we can then help to add the missing things?

Comment: I added the code now. My original code is pretty messy, so I cleaned it up and used the article class to produce a MWE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
+ \left\{ \begin{array}{rcr}
   x + y &= &1 \\ 
   x  - y &= &-1 \end{array} \right. \\
   \hline
 \begin{array}{rcr}
 2x & =&\hphantom{-}0
 \end{array}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Kinda! The `cases` environment allows me to use the system as an inline equation, can it be achieved like this?

Comment: Nevermind that, I found out that removing the `equation` environment worked!